# How to get the effect of chaining commands when they can't be chained?

Tags: shell, scripting, posix

I want to run a series of commands in order only if the previous command succeeded. According to [Shell scripts: Perils of “set -e” for error handling](http://david.rothlis.net/shell-set-e/):

> The recommendation is to do your own error checking by stringing
>   together a series of commands with “&&” like this:
>
> ```
> mkdir abc &&
> cd abc &&
> do_something_else &&
> last_thing ||
> { echo error >&2; exit 1; }
> ```

In the situation in which there has to be some script logic between some of the commands (such as a loop or complex conditionals), what is the idiomatic way to capture the status to a variable then use the variable again to ensure additional commands only execute if earlier commands were successful?

Something like:

```
mkdir abc
status=$?
... # do stuff (which might alter $?)
$status && cd abc
status=$?
... # do more stuff
$status && do_something_else
status=$?
... # do even more
$status && last_thing
status=$?
... # do final stuff
$status || { echo error >&2; exit 1; }
```

Comment: at some point using "guarded commands" might make more sense, where each action (e.g. `mkdir ...`) has a corresponding test (e.g. `[ -d ... ]`) and the action is only done if the test fails (the shell probably isn't a good language to implement that in, though)

Comment: True, this can be useful in many situations. But even in those cases it may also depend on a previous command succeeding, which might mean combining the tests (e.g. `$status && [ -d abc ] && cd abc`).

Comment: (In the example in my comment it's redundant, but there are many situations where it's not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was writing out this question, I realized one possible solution would be:

```
mkdir abc || { echo error >&2; exit 1; }
... # do stuff (which might alter $?)
cd abc || { echo error >&2; exit 1; }
... # do more stuff
do_something_else || { echo error >&2; exit 1; }
... # do even more
last_thing || { echo error >&2; exit 1; }
... # do final stuff
```

In this case, no `$status` variable is even needed and commands will execute only if the previous ones succeeded. And, I also realize, this is where a `die "error message"` function would come in handy to echo the error message and exit with error code.

---

### Update

With [`die`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7869048), it would be:

```
die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }

mkdir abc || die "error"
... # do stuff
cd abc || die "error"
... # do more stuff
do_something_else || die "error"
... # do even more
last_thing || die "error"
... # do final stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly cleaner (to my eye) version of what is in the OP's self-provided answer might be:

```
bail() {
  return=${1-1} # if no parameters sent, default to exit code 1
  shift
  echo "$@" 1>&2
  exit $return
}

if mkdir abc; then
  do_stuff
else
  bail 1 "Unable to create directory"
fi
if cd abc; then
  do_stuff
else
  bail 2 "Unable to enter directory"
fi
# et cetera
```

The crux being giving each failure case its own exit code, and this construct also allowing you to do your own failure case management in each `else` clause before firing `bail()`.

Comment: I should note that I used `bail` rather than `die` mainly out of habit, as I've done this sort of thing before and that's the function name that stuck in my head.

Comment: I didn't think about putting the commands within if conditionals, but for some situations and for non-trivial error handling scenarios it makes sense.

Comment: You can even nest them more easily this way (e.g. move the `if cd abc` command block inside the `then` stanza of the `if mkdir abc` block).